# Adding PDF with Javascript takes mouse focus

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe

I'm using Javascript to load a PDF in an iframe on my web page.

It's not an option to just do:

```
<iframe id="some" src="some.pdf" ...></iframe>
```

I really need to add the pdf later using Javascript like:

```
document.getElementById("some").src = "some.pdf";
```

My problem is that when the PDF loads it gets the focus for the mouse. I mean, when you try to scroll, instead of having the page scrolling you have a PDF scrolling. This is corrected when I click on another tab and return to the tab with the pdf.

Is there a way to add a PDF using Javascript but disabling the auto focus? Is using an iframe to display PDFs in the page like this even good?

Comment: Have you tried setting focus back on the document or other field in the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the pdf to be part of a page you have to use iframes. When you don't want it to be focused after load you just listen for the load event and put focus on an other element.

```
document.getElementById('some').onload= function() {
    document.getElementById('otherElement').focus();
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to implement something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Force focus on another element on your page after PDF load

```
var mywhatever = document.getElementById("mywhatever"); 
mywhatever.focus();
```